# Matplotlib boxplot and lineplot in one Graph - on labels with corresponding x-axis

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, boxplot, line-plot

In matplotlib, I want to boxplot and lineplot in same graph based on same labels
(normally on index of a pandas `df`, but for simplicity the following code)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# data
box_data = {'a': [1,10], 'b': [2,12], 'c': [3,13]}
line_data = {'a':1, 'b':2 , 'c':3}
labels = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3']

fig, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(9, 4), sharex=True)

bplot1 = axes.boxplot(box_data.values(), labels=labels)
line_plot = axes.plot( list(line_data.values()) )

plt.show()
plt.close('all')
```

Comment: You should create a toy pandas df that reflects your real conditions. Otherwise, we just solve pseudo problems that may not be transferable to your original problem.

Comment: I always take out part of main-code into a simple as possible - test.py -  to test what I'm doing wrong.. and build on that. As I want to 'understand' what I'm doing wrong {here 0 position to 1 position}. not looking for a quick fix of my code. (Thank you for text/language edit)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `boxplot` command labels ticks from `1` while `plot` labels ticks from `0`. You can try:

```
bplot1 = axes.boxplot(box_data.values(), labels=labels)
ticks = axes.get_xticks()
line_plot = axes.plot(ticks, list(line_data.values()) )
```

Output:

[image]